# Show info window on map loaded with ngmap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, typescript, ng-map

I'm using ng-map and typescript.
This is my template :

```
<map on-tilesloaded="showInfoWindow('myInfoWindow')" center="{{model.adresseLatitude}}, {{model.adresseLongitude}}" zoom="15" style="height: 425px">
    <marker id="gmapMarker" on-click="showInfoWindow('myInfoWindow')" position="{{model.adresseLatitude}}, {{model.adresseLongitude}}">
        <info-window id="myInfoWindow">
            <div ng-non-bindable="">
                {{model.adresse}}
            </div>
        </info-window>
    </marker>
</map>
```

When the map is loaded the infoWindow is shown on the top left of the map but it works fine when the marker is clicked.

I would like that the infowindow open at the right place (on the marker) when the map is displayed.

Comment: I have edited my question to be more precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `on-tilesloaded="showInfoWindow('myInfoWindow')"` in `map` directive you can use `visible-on-marker="markerID"` in `<info-window>` tag. i.e: `<info-window id="myInfoWindow" visible-on-marker="markerID">`

like:

```
<map center="{{model.adresseLatitude}}, {{model.adresseLongitude}}" zoom="15" style="height: 425px">
    <marker id="gmapMarker" on-click="showInfoWindow('myInfoWindow')" position="{{model.adresseLatitude}}, {{model.adresseLongitude}}">
        <info-window id="myInfoWindow" visible-on-marker="gmapMarker">
            <div ng-non-bindable="">
                {{model.adresse}}
            </div>
        </info-window>
    </marker>
</map>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I wanted !